# Java - How to use a dependency without compile it with the Gradle project

Tags: java, api, compilation, gradle, dependencies

I'm working on a project: https://github.com/Romain-P/Jumbo

- Jumbo-API
- Jumbo-Common
- Jumbo-Login (main project)

Jumbo-Login use API & Commons dependencies, but common depends on API & API on common.

So gradle want to do that:

1. Compile API.jar + Common.jar
2. Compile Common.jar + Api.jar
3. Compile login.jar + API.jar + Common.jar

We've so a stackoverflow exception.. So i thought to do not adding dependencies to API & Common because they will be in the same .jar after (in the Login.jar)

But Gradle doesn't want ! He return to me an error, and it say i MUST declare my dependencies to compile the global project.

Do you have the solution ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
dependencies {
  provided 'your-dependency'
}
```

You must apply the Intellij plugin ;)

Comment: Would love some reference to the documentation.